# python re - split a string before a character

Tags: python, regex, split

how to split a string at positions before a character?

- split a string before 'a'
- input: "fffagggahhh"
- output: ["fff", "aggg", "ahhh"]

the obvious way doesn't work:

```
>>> h=re.compile("(?=a)")

>>> h.split("fffagggahhh")

['fffagggahhh']

>>>
```

Comment: What do you expect when you split `"aaa"` — `['', 'a', 'a', 'a']` or `['a', 'a', 'a']`?

Comment: "aaa" -> "a", "a", "a" or "", "a", "a", "a"

Comment: -1: "aaa" -> ["a", "a", "a"] or ["", "a", "a", "a"].  That's the least helpful thing I've ever seen.  Both are right?  In that case, no pattern can ever work.  Close this question.

Comment: either one of them will do. if you have coded in python before, you would know a simple filter(bool, L) will filter out the empty element.

Comment: @user496852: "either one of them will do".  False.  The **pattern** is entirely different.  We can't interpret your question without one definite, absolute fact.  Please pick one as the "correct" meaning of your question or close it.  Only one patterns is "right".  The other can be derived.  But one is "proper".

Comment: "aaa" -> ["", "a", "a", "a"] is the "proper" requirement, if you insist. :)

Comment: Did something change in Python? Now your "the obvious way" works flawlessly.

Answer (score 21):

Ok, not exactly the solution you want but I thought it will be a useful addition to problem here.

> Solution without re

Without re:

```
>>> x = "fffagggahhh"
>>> k = x.split('a')
>>> j = [k[0]] + ['a'+l for l in k[1:]]
>>> j
['fff', 'aggg', 'ahhh']
>>>
```

Comment: @knitti: Thanks. I understand it is not the re based solution and I wanted to write it first before I write re solution. By the time, I finished writing this, the re based solution had come.

Comment: yeah, why use a hammer on a single nail if you've got a nail shooter.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> rx = re.compile("(?:a|^)[^a]*")
>>> rx.findall("fffagggahhh")
['fff', 'aggg', 'ahhh']
>>> rx.findall("aaa")
['a', 'a', 'a']
>>> rx.findall("fgh")
['fgh']
>>> rx.findall("")
['']
```

Comment: -1 `re.findall("(?:^|a)[^a]*", "aaa")` produces `['', 'a', 'a']`

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> r=re.compile("(a?[^a]+)")
>>> r.findall("fffagggahhh")
['fff', 'aggg', 'ahhh']
```

EDIT:

This won't handle correctly double `a`s in the string:

```
>>> r.findall("fffagggaahhh")
['fff', 'aggg', 'ahhh']
```

KennyTM's re seems better suited.

Comment: I wonder if the OP would want to keep the empty string from the split if it started with an 'a'.

Comment: -1 Uncool. Fails on repeated a's ... e.g. "aaa" -> empty list

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

def split_before(pattern,text):
    prev = 0
    for m in re.finditer(pattern,text):
        yield text[prev:m.start()]
        prev = m.start()
    yield text[prev:]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print list(split_before("a","fffagggahhh"))
```

re.split treats the pattern as a delimiter.

```
>>> print list(split_before("a","afffagggahhhaab"))
['', 'afff', 'aggg', 'ahhh', 'a', 'ab']
>>> print list(split_before("a","ffaabcaaa"))
['ff', 'a', 'abc', 'a', 'a', 'a']
>>> print list(split_before("a","aaaaa"))
['', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
>>> print list(split_before("a","bbbb"))
['bbbb']
>>> print list(split_before("a",""))
['']
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works on repeated `a`'s

```
  >>> re.findall("a[^a]*|^[^a]*", "aaaaa")
  ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a']
  >>> re.findall("a[^a]*|[^a]+", "ffaabcaaa")
  ['ff', 'a', 'abc', 'a', 'a', 'a']
```

Approach: the main chunks that you are looking for are an `a` followed by zero or more not-`a`. That covers all possibilities except for zero or more not-`a`. That can happen only at the start of the input string.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> foo = "abbcaaaabbbbcaaab"
>>> bar = foo.split("c")
>>> baz = [bar[0]] + ["c"+x for x in bar[1:]]
>>> baz
['abb', 'caaaabbbb', 'caaab']
```

Due to how slicing works, this will work properly even if there are no occurrences of `c` in `foo`.

Answer (score -3):

`split()` takes an argument for the character to split on:

```
>>> "fffagggahhh".split('a')
['fff', 'ggg', 'hhh']
```